# can I add additional subdomain in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a new team-site named team-sam I want to know if I can customize the url. my main site is named companyname.sharepoint.com, is there a way I can setup my new team site as teamsam.sharepoint.com

If possible I will have two sharepoint sites with url as companyname.sharepoint.com and teamsam.sharepoint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple domains from M365 Admin center as suggested by Renjie but you cannot have multiple subdomains for SharePoint under one tenant. if you have a SharePoint root url like companyname.sharepoint.com and you wish to have another one like teamsam.sharepoint.com then you need to create a new tenant.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new domain in Microsoft 365 admin center.
Before you begin, you must be a Domain Name Administrator or Global Administrator.
Follow these steps to add, set up, or continue setting up a domain:

1. Go to the Microsoft 365 admin center
2. Go to the Settings -> Domains page
3. Select Add domain.
4. Enter the name of the domain you want to add, then select Next.
5. Choose how you want to verify that you own the domain.
6. Choose how you want to make the DNS changes required for Microsoft to use your domain.
7. If you chose to add DNS records yourself , select Next and you'll see a page with all the records that you need to add to your registrars website to set up your domain.
8. Select Finish.

The following article may help you add a new domain step by step.

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-domain?view=o365-worldwide

Good luck,

Renjie Sun

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.